# c# Microsoft Access convertendo data

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Estou tendo problemas com INSERT e UPDATE pois na minha máquina as datas estão sendo convertidas automaticamente, mas nas máquinas dos usuários não.

Ex:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblPendencia " +
                                      " SET CarenciaInicio = " + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pendencia.CarenciaInicioData.Trim()) ? "null" : "#" + pendencia.CarenciaInicioData + "#") + "," +
                                          " CarenciaFim = " + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pendencia.CarenciaFimData.Trim()) ? "null" : "#" + pendencia.CarenciaFimData + "#") + "," +
                                          " AberturaData = " + (pendencia.AberturaData == null ? "null" : "#" + pendencia.AberturaData + "#") + "," +
                                          " VencimentoData = " + (pendencia.VencimentoData == null ? "null" : "#" + pendencia.VencimentoData + "#") + "," +
                                          " LiquidacaoData = " + (pendencia.LiquidacaoData == null ? "null" : "#" + pendencia.LiquidacaoData + "#") + "," +
                                          " CentroCusto = '" + pendencia.CentroCusto + "'," +
                                          " DiasDecorridos = " + pendencia.DiasDecorridos + "," +
                                          " Lastro = '" + pendencia.Lastro + "'," +
                                          " Corretora = '" + pendencia.Corretora + "'," +
                                          " AdAm = '" + pendencia.AdAm + "'," +
                                          " Observacao = '" + pendencia.Observacao + "'," +
                                          " Officer = '" + pendencia.Officer + "'," +
                                          " Segmento = '" + pendencia.Segmento + "'," +
                                          " Rating = '" + pendencia.Rating + "'," +
                                          " AlcadaTipo = '" + pendencia.AlcadaTipo + "'," +
                                          " Tipo = '" + pendencia.Tipo + "'" +
                                    " WHERE pendenciaNassauId = " + pendencia.PendenciaId, conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Executando essas queries na minha máquina irá salvar no access a data 11/07/2011, mas se um usuário executar na máquina dele irá salvar correto: 07/11/2011.

No desespero alterei o idioma do windows do office  e até do VS2013 na minha maquina, mas não funcionou.

Parameters: (Erro datatype mismatch)

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexao()))
{
    conn.Open();

    using(OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblLog "+
                          "([operadorId], [logTipoId], [logData], [pendenciaId], [valorFatorAnterior], [valorFatorNovo], [statusIdAnterior], [statusIdNovo], [porContratoIdAnterior], [porContratoIdNovo], [isAtivo]) " +
                          "VALUES ( @operadorId, @logTipoId, @logData, @optionalPendenciaId, @optionalValorFatorAnterior, @optionalValorFatorNovo, @optionalStatusIdAnterior, @optionalStatusIdNovo, @optionalPorContratoIdAnterior, @optionalPorContratoIdNovo, @optionalIsAtivo);";

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
        {
            new OleDbParameter("@operadorId", operadorId),
            new OleDbParameter("@logTipoId", logTipoId),
            new OleDbParameter("@logData", logData ),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalPendenciaId", optionalPendenciaId),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalValorFatorAnterior", "'" + optionalValorFatorAnterior + "'"),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalValorFatorNovo", "'" + optionalValorFatorNovo + "'"),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalStatusIdAnterior", optionalStatusIdAnterior),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalStatusIdNovo", optionalStatusIdNovo),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalPorContratoIdAnterior", optionalPorContratoIdAnterior),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalPorContratoIdNovo", optionalPorContratoIdNovo),
            new OleDbParameter("@optionalIsAtivo", optionalIsAtivo.ToString())                        
        });

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Testei da forma abaixo mas está dando datatype mismatch.

```
cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblLog " +
                           "([operadorId], [logTipoId], [logData], [pendenciaId], [valorFatorAnterior], [valorFatorNovo], [statusIdAnterior], [statusIdNovo], [porContratoIdAnterior], [porContratoIdNovo], [isAtivo]) " +
                   "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operadorId", operadorId);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logTipoId", logTipoId);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logData", logData );
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalPendenciaId", optionalPendenciaId);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalValorFatorAnterior", optionalValorFatorAnterior);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalValorFatorNovo", optionalValorFatorNovo);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalStatusIdAnterior", optionalStatusIdAnterior);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalStatusIdNovo", optionalStatusIdNovo);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalPorContratoIdAnterior", optionalPorContratoIdAnterior);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalPorContratoIdNovo", optionalPorContratoIdNovo);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalIsAtivo", optionalIsAtivo);

cmd1.Connection = conn1;
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn1.Close();
```

Comment: Coloque todo o código

Comment: Coloquei o update

Comment: porque não utiliza o [parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)? isso já resolve a conversão de data!

Comment: [Exemplo1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345830/update-command-parameters-in-c-sharp-for-access-2003-not-update) e [Exemplo 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database) não faça SQL pura, tem diversos problemas relacionados, então, deixo o framework trabalhar por você

Comment: @VirgilioNovic fiz com o parameters mas estou recebendo o erro de datatype mismatch, eu tenho que enviar os dados formatados? 

Ex: new OleDbParameter("@logData", logData ) ou new OleDbParameter("@logData",  "#" + logData + "#" ) ?

Comment: Eu fiz sem as aspas simples e sem o cercadilho, porém me retornou datatype mismatch tbm

Comment: `logData` é qual tipo?

Comment: No BD está como datetime.

Não sei se adiciona algo mas eu abri os parameters no cmd através do watch e lá estava como string.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Inseri as duas formas utilizando parameters, ambas estão dando datatype mismatch.

Comment: Eu reproduzi um exemplo com tipos de campos que geralmente são usados em uma tabela `ACCESS` e fiz uma respostas, verifique o que isso pode ajudar, porque, o seu erro está sendo de tipos diferentes. Observação: verifica a correlação entre os campos ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre quando for utilizar gravações de campos específicos (`datetime`, `decimal`, `double`, `bit`, etc), existe o [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) do [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) para converte de maneira correta os dados enviados para sua tabela em banco de dados `ACCESS` (*essa recomendação serve pra todos os bancos de dados*).

*Exemplo minimo:*

**Classe modelo:**

```
public class TableData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Tabela `Layout`:**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Execução do** `INSERT` **nessa tabela** `TableData`

```
TableData tableData = new TableData();
tableData.Name = "Name 1";
tableData.Created = DateTime.Now;
tableData.Value = 550.90m;
tableData.Status = false;  

string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\db2000.mdb";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{

    connection.Open();

    string strIns = "INSERT INTO TableData([Name], [Created], [Value], [Status]) ";
    strIns += " VALUES(@Name, @Created, @Value, @Status);";

    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = strIns;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = tableData.Name;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Created", OleDbType.Date).Value = tableData.Created;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Value", OleDbType.Single).Value = tableData.Value;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Status", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = tableData.Status;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Para `UPDATE` segue a mesma idéia do `INSERT` só alterar a `SQL`.

<sub>**Observação:** Sempre faça uma classe para representar seus dados, isso ajuda na manutenção, padroniza seu código e organiza cada informação.</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [Classe OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Propriedade OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Estrutura Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou perfeitamente! Acredito que ele estava de perdendo com os tipo! Obrigado Virgilio!!